# MySQL Query to determine Value based on 3 Variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to be able to pinpoint a value in a MySQL table which is defined by two variables.

On the frontend of the site, there is a form which accepts a variety of fields.  For this example let’s focus on these two:

1. Account Number
2. Account Name

I have developed a script which will use an ajax script to check the “Account Number” once entered and if it finds a match will display the “Account Name” when the user tabs out of the field.

The difficulty is to find a single result from the format of the database tables.  For example:

```
”SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE name=’$accountnumber’”
```

Provides a list of all the values that equal the account number, but does not provide any record of the account name.

`”SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE name=’$accountname’”`

Provides a list of all the values that equal the account names, but does not provide any record of the account number.

The `$record` value is the only common thread between `$accountnumber` and `$accountname`.

So all in all, I need assistance creating the loop which can first take the `$accountnumber` value to find the `$record` value associated with that number. Secondly it will take the determined `$record` value and match it to the `$accountname` value.  There is only one `$accountnumber` and `$accountname` value per unique `$record` value.

---

UPDATED:  There have been several good comments on this question.  To help provide more background, there is only one table.  The best discriminator available seems to be the `title` value.  Here is a link to the table snippet to view in greater detail:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By2lFlhEzILjbE1uT1hkVURmczA/edit?usp=sharing

So ultimately in this sample, a user would type `246802` and the result that is filtered out would be `Fred’s Account`.

Comment: Read about joins. Your question has an incredibly simple answer if you just take a little bit of time to learn the fundamentals of sql.

Comment: @Colleen I think he might be asking something slightly more complex - but the question needs work to know for sure.

Comment: @Matthew yeah, I assumed that the identical table names were a typo or an implication of 2 different tables, from the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like these are in the same table? Is there any discriminator to tell you whether `name` holds an `accountnumber` or `accountname`?

In any even, with the following assumptions you could try an ugly self join:

1. There are only two records with the record ID you want
2. these are multiple columns in the same table holding different information in the ambiguous column names
3. there is no better way to discriminate the record type

If so, something like this self-join should get you started:

```
SELECT t2.name as accountnumber from example_table as t1
INNER JOIN example_table as t2 on t1.recordID=t2.recordID
WHERE t1.name='$accountname'
```

**EDIT** Note - if my assumptions are correct and if this is data you are inheriting, I feel for you and you should look to improve it's structure. If you are designing it like this, you may want to think about it some more first.

**EDIT 2**

You probably want to put an index on the `name` column (this is the discriminator I would used based on your example).

Your query can be something like this:

```
SELECT t1.value as accountnumber,t2.value as accountName from example_table as t1
INNER JOIN example_table as t2 on t1.record=t2.record
WHERE t1.name='accountNumber' and t2.name='accountName'
```

See this SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97c2f/1

Comment: You are correct that these items are all in the same table.  Thank you for the thorough reply.  I am going to do some research on your answer and learn a bit more about `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` and then will be back with an update.

Comment: Above you asked:

Is there any discriminator to tell you whether name holds an accountnumber or accountname?

Yes, the best discriminator available seems to be the `title` value.  Here is a link to the table snippet to view in greater detail:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By2lFlhEzILjbE1uT1hkVURmczA/edit?usp=sharing

So ultimately in this sample, a user would type `246802` and the result that is filtered out would be `Fred’s Account`.  Thanks again.

Comment: Another note, I am working within a pre-defined table structure from a web application.  The client has requested to work within the provided structure, so I am avoiding any table redesigning.

Comment: Updated to answer your questions